# How to execute a program within a Jar file

Tags: java, jar, processbuilder

Soo my problem is, that I made some kind of launcher and wrote a method that is being called if you click on the "play" button.

```
private void PlayButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    try 
    {
        new ProcessBuilder("src/calc.exe").start(); 
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) 
    {
        Logger.getLogger(Launcher.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

The file that is being executed is just a copy of the calculator from Windows and 
is in the src folder of my project. (Path is "src/calc.exe")

Everything works fine AS LONG as I don't compile my netbeans project file into a JAR file.

If I run the JAR file and click on the play button - nothing happens.

I really hope you can tell me how to fix this.

(P.S.: calc.exe is not always the name of the program to be run. The filename is determined by an .ini. 
calc.exe is only used to test the program.)

Comment: JAR files don't have that permission by default I think.

Comment: @LeventeKurusa: You may be thinking of applets. I doubt that this has anything to do with permission.

Comment: Yes, I somehow ended up believing this was all way about applets. Sorry about that, my eyes are getting old or something :o

Comment: Jonas: does your log file have any data? Also, you know that you should be running that process on a background thread, right?

Comment: Jonas: What is this: `... ("src/calc.exe").start;`
I think you forgot something.

Comment: This is the only path that is used. It works in the project so I don't think that's the problem :|

Comment: I was talking about that you had forgotten to add `()` to the end.

Comment: ah yeah; you are right. Sorry about that, I fixed it in my post. Looks like I forgot to copy that bit from my project;

Comment: Also who downvoted my question?? And why?
Edit: NVM ;)

Comment: I upvoted it back to zero, so it stays on top, because I think it is interesting.
Please create some debug messages, like "PlayClicked". After that, let's see where it fails.

Comment: The path might change when running it from the jar file and then it won't find the exe.

Comment: I added a debug message before and after new ProcessBuilder("src/calc.exe").start();
The message before the call is shown, the one after isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, some context:

- A `JAR` file is an archive, a package (compressed or not) that contains Java bytecode and other resources that can be consumed from inside a JVM.
- An `EXE` file is executable binary file that can only be understandable by Windows/MS-DOS family OSs.

When you run your program without packaging it into a JAR file, all resources (the class file and the executable) are accessible from the OS. Windows will launch the JVM and from inside there you, by means of the `ProcessBuilder`, instruct the OS to invoke an executable file accessible in a path which is relative to the class performing the execution instruction. Until there, everything is fine and as you said, it works.

However, when you pack your Java class and the executable file in a JAR and invoke the JAR, its **contents are no longer accessible for the OS**. What is happening is that the OS will launch the JVM and it will process the JAR file to find the executable class (the one in which you invoke the `ProcessBuilder`). From that class file you now instruct the OS to launch an executable which is in a path relative to the JAR file instead of being relative to the class file performing the invoke instruction. Since the EXE is **inside the JAR file instead of being relative to it**, execution fails because it can't find the executable.

This is that way because the OS won't look inside the JAR file for a specific file, for the OS the JAR file is just that, a file, not a folder so it will ignore its contents.

So, the conclusion is that, since you are invoking the OS to perform a specific operation in another file, just must place that file outside the JAR and in a relative path to that JAR.

If for some reason you insist on packaging your EXE inside the JAR, then you need to extract it outside the JAR before invoking the `ProcessBuilder` to a temporary folder and invoke the `ProcessBuilder` using that new path.

Comment: Thank you (: That really helped me. I now use MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()); to get the path and then just add the name of the program I want to start. And it works! (:
Again; thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

This is sort of a touchy subject.

Whoever commented that JARs are not able to do this is wrong. To the contrary, it is applets that do not have such a permission unless they are signed and validated by the author through Oracle.

You said that it all works fine unless you put it in a JAR. That is probably because of your URI being relative to the Windows filesystem.

The way to usually get the file regardless of the packaging around the reference is to do something like this:

```
    MainClass.class.getResourceAsStream(file);
```

The static getResourceAsStream will parse the available relative and absolute paths, and if you put your "src/calc.exe" here, it should work.

Another suggestion is to thread the process opening. If you have the program as a single thread, the Java program will hang until the external process is gone and cleaned up.

Comment: Of course, you will need to use an InputStreamReader, probably wrapped in a convenience class, like BufferedReader in order to get the data out of the file.

Comment: The thing is I just want start the file and not read from it.

Comment: Yes, and you can still use this. Probably better would be the method in the same hierarchy getResource, as you can read it into the File class, and then convert it up to a Process.