# Run C programs inside a .jar file

Tags: java, c, progress

I have a couple of compiled C programs. In my Java program with process I run them to obtain the output from the C programs. The problem I'm facing is that I want to run these C files within a jar file instead of having the programs in the same folder as the jar file.

I have been searching through the internet if something similar was done but unfortunately I couldn't find anything similar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute a program within a Jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147656/how-to-execute-a-program-within-a-jar-file)

Comment: Can't be done afaik. You'd need to use some sort of 'executor' that could run an executable from a stream as opposed to a file. I don't know of one

Comment: It's theoretically possible, but you'd probably need a DLL which has to be extracted into a folder anyway...